# My ties to Home Country for Canadian Temporary Residence Visa

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I plan on going for a Tour in Canada for say 20 Days, Hotel reservation, Feeding etc. Would be sponsored by me. I dont have an immediate or extended family to invite me to Canada, just family friends. This is generally all information about me :

- I do not have a travel history
- I have a Business and Landed property inherited by me from my father and grand father.
- I have a stable job with stable salary here in Nigeria
- I am married, do not have a child

Do you think its a good fit to apply, bearing in mind I dont have a family in Canada, And I do not have an Invitation? I am from Nigeria

Comment: Having an invitation is not a mandatory requirement. Your lack of travel history is a minus, as is your citizenship given that jurisdictions generally view Nigeria as a high immigration risk country. Your family, job, and ownership of property in Nigeria are pluses. Apart from that, no-one can say with any certainty what the outcome of an application would be. If I were you, I would build up a travel history before attempting an application to Canada or any of the equivalent jurisdictions such as Schengen, but I may be more risk-averse than you are.

Comment: I would add that you need not say how you came to own the real property; the "inherited by me" phrase is unnecessary. The importance of the property is its ownership by you, not how you came the ownership.